# Convert a list of interactions into a matrix in Python

Tags: python

Whats the most efficient way to convert a list of interactions such as this:

```
QWERT     ASDF      12
QWERT     ZXCV      15
QWERT     HJKL      6
:             :     :
ASDF-XYZ  HJKL-XYY  123
```

into an all vs all matrix representation such as this:

```
            QWERT   ASDF   ZXCV   ...   ASDF-XYZ
QWERT       0       12     15     ...   9
ASDF        12      0      45     ...   35
ZXCV        15      45     0      ...   24
:           :       :      :      :     :
ASDF-XYZ    9       35     24     ...   0
```

It could be a few thousand up to several hundred thousands of features, so speed does matter.

Edit: The input is a csv file. Please note that the feature names are arbitrary (but unique) strings and that missing interaction should be represented as 0 in the output matrix. Made the example more clear.

Comment: Do you expect the result matrix to be dense or sparse? What is the input datatype? What datatype you expect as outoput?

Comment: The input is a csv file with said list of interactions, and I expect the output to be a dense matrix, which includes zeroes for entries missing in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy` for this
lets say the input:

`points = [(1,2,12), (1,3,15), (1,4,6)]`

the first point is on the cordinates, (1,2) and it value is 12

you can use the the numpy function `add.at`:

```py
table = numpy.zeros((5,5))
points = [(1,2,12), (1,3,15), (1,4,6)]
for point in points:
     numpy.add.at(table, tuple(zip(i[0:2])), i[2])
np.rot90(table)
```

which leaves you with the output:

```
array([[ 0.,  6.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 15.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 12.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

you can pretty easily modife the code so it print the headers too

Comment: Thanks, what would be the best way to match the feature names to numerical arguments in your opinion? I guess string matching on a list of a hundred thousand feature strings can be a bit slow.

Comment: @bgbrink im guessing its always in the same format? you can use ```str.split('-')[1]``` to get the numbers, and then put those prefix when you needs to print it

Comment: unfortunately the naming can be arbitrary, but is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @bgbrink you can go with regex if you need so, but i think if you know the seperator between the name and the integer, you can just use split

Comment: I meant arbitrary in the way that it can be any ID and most of the time, there will not be an integer present at all. Sorry for not being clear about that from the start.

Comment: Can you specifie in your question another cases?

Comment: I changed the example in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're reading a CSV, you could use pandas and `pivot`. This will not give you an `n * n` array, but an `n1 * n2` array, where `n1` and `n2` are the unique values in the first and second column, respectively.

```py
import pandas as pd

# For exposition, replace with data.
df = pd.DataFrame([["XYZ", "ABC", 10], 
                   ["ASDF", "XYZ", 100],
                   ["BSDF", "ABC", 1000]], columns=("id1", "id2", "value"))

pv = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                    values="value", 
                    index="id1",
                    columns="id2",
                    fill_value=0)
```